# Разбор странной строки кода в классе

Tags: javascript

Интересуют две строчки кода помеченные внизу. Это инициализация или переменная с именем класса? Я запутался, помогите понять, что это? Как правильно называть эти две строки кода?

```js
class User {
  constructor(name, age) { // Это тоже инициализация аргументов функции?
    this.names = name;
    this.ages = age;
  }

  hi() {
    alert(this.names);
  }

  age() {
    alert(this.ages);
  }
}

let user = new User('opa', 32); // ***** Это инициализация переменной или что? ******
user.hi();
user.age();
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/es-class

Comment: Это функция-конструктор класса

Comment: 1. Я бы назвал это декларацией конструктора класса. 2. Это инициализация переменной user значением экземпляра класса User

Comment: @entithat, constructor(name, age) создает функцию с двумя аргументами внутри класса User, верно ли я понимаю?

Comment: @ЯнЗамойский, нет, неверно

Comment: @ЯнЗамойский Вы инициализируете new class. Это означает, что вам доступны методы, которые публичны в этом классе - снаружи. Вы инициализируете User, создавая как бы инстанс класса с его входными данными name, age, далее вы в  this  сохраняете этот под names и ages. Вы создаете методы которые в конструкторе, но используете их снаружи. Можно попробовать почитать по теме  SOLID, может что-то вам станет понятно и от туда.

Comment: constructor(a, b) ничего не создает, меня смущает ваша терминология. constructor(a, b) указывает на то, что в классе User при создании экземпляра обьекта будет выполняться код этой функции.

Comment: @WalkMess спасибо, а на какой строке кода происходит инициализация?

Comment: Ну это уже слишком.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

До закрывающих двойных скобок создаётся класс `User` (шаблон для создания объектов), c 2-мя аргументами `name`, `age`, и с 2-мя методами, т.е. функциями, которые можно применить к этому объекту.

```
let user = new User('opa', 32);
```

Это создание объекта:

```
user {
    names = 'opa', ages = 32} `
```

Comment: constructor(name, age) создает объект?  Может он создает функцию?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/class

Comment: Constructor - это служебная функция которая создаёт шаблон для создания объектов которые будет принимать(записывать при создании) две переменные "name" и "age". Это трудно объяснить в рамках 4 строчек. Вот основной материал по теме:
https://learn.javascript.ru/object 
https://learn.javascript.ru/class

Comment: _Constructor - это служебная функция которая создаёт шаблон для создания объектов_ - это неверно.

Comment: Я в курсе, что это метод. А что такое метод? Это прописанная функция внутри объекта. Да, моё объяснение не точное, но попробуй объяснить понятнее человеку который даже с объектами не знаком.

Comment: @Grundy, ну  а что верно?
Вы хоть скажите, если вам это не трудно =)